# Top quark decay rate calculation $\Gamma(t\rightarrow W^+b)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, electroweak

I'm trying to calculate the disintegration rate $\Gamma(t\rightarrow W^+b)$ from the Fermi Diagram:

[image]

I know the lagrangian for the interaction would be: 
$$ -iF = \bar{u_b}\gamma^\mu P_Li\frac{g}{\sqrt2}U_{tb}\delta_{ij}u_t \epsilon^\mu $$
Hence, the $$|\bar{F}|^2 = \frac{g^2}{4}\sum \bar{u_b}\gamma^\mu P_Lu_t \bar{u_t} P_R\gamma^\nu u_b \epsilon^\mu \epsilon^{*\nu}$$

Then, I transform the sum into the trace, and substitute the $P_L = \frac{1-\gamma^5}{2}$, eliminating the $\gamma^5$ since it's asymmetrical. 
I don't want to make any approximation with the masses in order to reproduce the result in the [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-top-quark.pdf).

$$ |\bar{F}|^2 = \frac{g^2}{8}Tr[(P_b+m_b)\gamma^\mu(P_t+m_t)\gamma^\nu] \epsilon^\mu \epsilon^{*\nu}$$

This is where I get lost, not sure how to operate with the trace in order to obtain the momentum of each particle. Not sure either if my reasoning with the lagrangian is correct.

Comment: The trace of two gamma matrices is trivial, I hope you know, but your application of Casimir's trick for fermion bilinear and collapse of chiral projectors looks problematic, at the very least:  Why don't you show your work on that? Have you worked out muon decay in class?

Comment: @CosmasZachos We haven't worked on that yet, but I'll do it as an exercise, why does the Casimir's trick seems problematic? I just skipped the steps on the indexes, what I did was "eliminating" the chiral projectors with $\gamma^5$ because it's asymetrical and the chiral projectors are symetrical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of algebra, I came to the solution as follows:
$$ |\bar{F}|^2 = \frac{g^2}{8}4(P_{b\mu}P_{t\nu} + P_{b\nu}P_{t\mu} - P_bP_tg_{\mu\nu} + m_bm_tg_{\mu\nu})(-g^{\mu\nu}M_w^2+P^{\mu}_wP^{\nu}_w)$$
Contracting the indexes and asuming $m_b \approx 0$ in order to get the result of the PDG:
$$ |\bar{F}|^2 = \frac{g^2}{8}4(P_tP_b+\frac{2P_tP_wP_bP_w}{M_w^2}) $$
Using $P_t = P_w+P_b \rightarrow P_t^2 = m_t^2=(P_w+P_b)^2$:
$$ |\bar{F}|^2 = \frac{g^2}{8}4(\frac{m_t^2-m_w^2}{2}+\frac{(m_t^2-m_w^2)(m_t^2+m_w^2)}{2M_w^2}) $$
Knowing that $\Gamma(t\rightarrow W^+b) = \frac{\bar{F}|^2}{2m_t}\int dLips$
and $$\int dLips = \frac{m_t^2-m_w^2}{8\pi m_t^2}$$ for this specific case
$$ \Gamma(t\rightarrow W^+b) = \frac{g^2}{64\pi}\frac{m_t^3}{m_w^2}(1-\frac{m_w^2}{m_t^2})^2(1+2\frac{m_w^2}{m_t^2}) $$